# enhancing skel-layers, looking for comments

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design

as my JS skills are still "in the making" I'm looking for links to start reading how this could be accomplished...

I'm using a [responsive template](https://www.html5webtemplates.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/Elements.zip) on my website based on skel and skel-layers. Yes, these are age old but they're lightweighted and do an excellent job so I'd like to keep them if it's reasonable.

Since my site has grown, the sidebar menu generated by [skel-layers.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ajlkn/skel.old/master/src/skel-layers.js) has become overcrowded as all menu items (navList) of all levels are always expanded/visible.
I'd like all menu items to be collapsed by default and if they carry sub-menus, an icon (eg down-chevron) should be appended for the menu item to expand upon tipping/clicking.

If you think it's not worth the effort of doing this with skel-layers please let me know and I'd appreciate any hints where to look for reasonable templates/codes in the style/behaviour of skel that would do this. But TBH, I'd really like to find out if this could be coded into skel-layers as it would be a great excercise for me - just need a jump start...

Many thanks.